# When I fetch using GET method I receive an error 502

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When I try to fetch using GET I recieve an error 502 but when I fetch using POST i recieve the response.

Lambda:

```
const headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}


exports.handler = async function(event) {
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        headers
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({"ok":"ok"})
    }
};
```

Fetch:

```
fetch("https://n3bvznv385.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/juegos", {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'authorizationToken' : '123',
            }
        }).then(response => response.json())
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
            .then(response => console.log(JSON.parse(response.body)));
```

[Error using GET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw2v6.png)
[Success using POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv7yh.png)

Comment: 500 error means something went wrong on the server side for the get request. Check your server logs or post it here.

Comment: Also check if the `GET` and `POST` operations are configured okay in APIGW.

Comment: What is `'Content-Type': 'application/json',` doing there? You've making a GET request. You can't have a JSON body (or any body)

Comment: @Quentin Thank you I will remember it, I've deleted it but nothing happens.

Comment: @DavidOrtiz do you have Lambda Proxy integration configured in API Gateway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Gateway [expects the following response format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format) from your Lambda when you are using Proxy Integration:

```
{
    "isBase64Encoded": true|false,
    "statusCode": httpStatusCode,
    "headers": { "headerName": "headerValue", ... },
    "multiValueHeaders": { "headerName": ["headerValue", "headerValue2", ...], ... },
    "body": "..."
}
```

You are, however, passing a nested object as headers as your code resolves to this:

`headers: { {'Content-Type':'application/json'} }`.

Try to include possible headers like this instead:

```
exports.handler = async function(event) {
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify({"ok":"ok"})
    }
};
```